# Creating new model in Django with POST data from Python requests

Tags: python, django, post, python-requests

I'm trying to take information from a POST request made from Python requests and add them to my model:

```
def message(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputInfoForm(request.POST)
        #form models make validation easy
        if form.is_valid():
            InputInfo.name = request.POST.get('name')
            InputInfo.conversation_id = request.POST.get('conversation_id')
            InputInfo.message_body = request.POST.get('message_body')


        return HttpResponse(status=200)

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Here's the request

```
post_data = {'name': 'charles', 'conversation_id': '3', 'message_body': 'Ada Challenge'}
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/message/', data=post_data)
```

I am not sure if I am handling the requests right in the view

Comment: Is `InputInfoForm` a model form?

Comment: Yes it is and `InputForm` is just the regular model

Comment: You can just do `form.save()` if its model form to create a new object.

Comment: I tried that before and it tells me `InputInfoForm` has no attribute save

Comment: Add code snippet of `InputInfoForm`.

Comment: Hey sorry when you asked me if it was a model form did you mean `forms.ModelForm` if so sorry I misinterpreted that. It's working now, it was `forms.Form` before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments that `InputInfoForm` is a `ModelForm`. So you can call `form.save` method after calling `form.is_valid` method.

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save() # This method will handle data saving part, no need to assign explicitly
```